# React.js re-render behavior changes when list contents change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This question requires some background to understand:

My app uses various lists of items with Boolean state that the user toggles by clicking.

I implemented this logic with two reusable elements:

- A custom hook, `useSelections()`, which maintains an array of objects of the form `{ id, name, isSelected }`, where `isSelected` is Boolean and the only mutable element. It returns the array as current state, and a dispatch function that takes an input of the form `{ id, newValue }` and updates the `isSelected` member of the object with the given `id`
- A function component `Selector`, which takes as props a single item and the dispatch from `useSelections` and returns a `<li>` element whose CSS class depends on `isSelected`.

Normally, they are used together in the following way, which works fine (i.e., internal state and the color of the list item are synchronized, and toggle when clicked):

```
function localComponent(props) {
const [items, dispatch] = useSelections(props.data);

return (
  <ul>
    {items.map(item => <Selector key={item.id} item={item} onChange={dispatch} />)}
  </ul>
);
}
```

It works equally well when `useSelections()` is elevated to a parent component, and `items` and `dispatch` are passed as props.

The trouble started when the array became larger, and I decided to page it:

```
<ul>
   {items.slice(start, end).map(item => <Selector key={item.id} item={item} onChange={dispatch} />)}
</ul>
```

(`start` and `end` are part of component state.)

When my component is first rendered, it works normally. However, once `start` and `end` are changed (to move to the next page), clicking an item changes internal state, but no longer triggers a re-render. In UX terms this means that after the first 'next' click, when I click on an item nothing appears to happen, but if I hit 'next' again, and then 'back', the item I just clicked on has now changed.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds to me like variables are being mutated rather than stored and updated with `useState`. 

Are you using `useState` inside your custom hook to maintain this array? And are you using the `set` function it gives you in your dispatch function?

Comment: @Laurence That was my first thought. The custom hook uses `useReducer`, and passes the dispatch function through. The reducer function wraps the array in a new object. Also, it re-renders until I start paging.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing the logic from the reducer function to ignore calls where there is no change:

```
const hasChanged = modifiedItem.isSelected !== newValue;
modifiedItem.isSelected = newValue;
return hasChanged ? { data } : state;
```

is now simply:

```
modifiedItem.isSelected = newValue;
return { data };
```

There's still something going on with React here that I do not understand, but my immediate problem is solved.